# Composing C++ classes with members that have extended types

Tags: c++

How does one in C++ compose a class that has members which are types that have extensions? Take an example of a car. We have a `Car` and a `BigCar`. The `Car` comes with an `Engine` but the `BigCar` should come with a `BigEngine`. But if we just hide the `engine` member of `BigCar` with `BigEngine`, regular `Engine` will still be created and might do something during construction that we don't want. Is there a better way? Or is the only way to "not do anything during construction." I know we could use DIC but I think there is a really obvious way I am not thinking of...

Example

```
#include <iostream>

class Engine {
public:
    Engine() {
        this->cylinders = 4;
    }
    virtual ~Engine() {}
    int cylinders;
};

class BigEngine : public Engine {
public:
    BigEngine():Engine() {
        this->cylinders = 8;
        this->fuel_injector = true;
    }
    bool fuel_injector;
};

class Car {
public:
    Car() {
        std::cout << this->engine.cylinders;
    }
    virtual ~Car(){ }
    Engine engine;
};

class BigCar : public Car {
public:
    BigCar():Car() {
        std::cout << this->engine.fuel_injector;
    }
    ~BigCar() { }
    BigEngine engine;
};

int main()
{
    BigCar car; // SHOULD print 81 but prints 41
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a template:

```
#include <iostream>

class Engine {
public:
    Engine() : cylinders{4} {}
    int cylinders;
};

class BigEngine : public Engine {
public:
    BigEngine() : Engine{}, fuel_injector{true} {
        this->cylinders = 8;
    }
    bool fuel_injector;
};

template<typename E = Engine>
class Car {
public:
    Car() {
        std::cout << this->engine.cylinders;
    }
    E engine;
};

class BigCar : public Car<BigEngine> {
public:
    BigCar(): Car<BigEngine>{} {
        std::cout << this->engine.fuel_injector;
    }
};


int main()
{
    BigCar car;
}
```

This has the problem, though, that there won't be one single `Car` class. Still, if you want to store different types of engines in the `Car` (types with different sizes), you need to store pointers instead. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Engine {
public:
    Engine() : cylinders{4} {}
    int cylinders;
};

class BigEngine : public Engine {
public:
    BigEngine() : Engine{}, fuel_injector{true} {
        this->cylinders = 8;
    }
    bool fuel_injector;
};

class Car {
public:
    Car() : Car{std::make_unique<Engine>()} {
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Engine> engine;
protected:
    Car(std::unique_ptr<Engine> engine) : engine{std::move(engine)} {
        std::cout << this->engine->cylinders;
    }
};

class BigCar : public Car {
public:
    BigCar(): Car{std::make_unique<BigEngine>()} {
        std::cout << static_cast<BigEngine*>(this->engine.get())->fuel_injector;
    }
};


int main()
{
    BigCar car;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Car` class can have a pointer to an `Engine`, and the appropriate engine could be created in constructo. That would take care of the different engine types when you'd have to add electric :)